# How to encode special apostrophe using htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

Im encoding the string **I’m a student** using htmlspecialchars() function and the apostrophe is being encoded as **I???m a student**

Im guessing its because, the person who entered the text has copy pasted the text from some other editor and the apostrophe is not the usual one.

How can I fix this? Is there any function in PHP to handle these also?

Comment: have you tried setting your charset to `utf-8`?

Comment: Why do you think this depends on using `htmlspecialchars()`? If you just include the text as-is, is the result the same? Apparently, you have a UTF-8 encoded string that is being misinterprered as ISO-8859-1 encoded, or something like that—a problem with character encoding for the entire page.